Conference Organization and Academic Journal - Not known
I recently had a paper accepted at an international conference, which means that if I attend and participate, my paper will be included in the conference proceedings. Additionally, if the paper performs well, I may be invited to submit an extended version for publication in a journal affiliated with the conference. The journal appears in the list called OAJI.net (Open Academic Journals Index).
However, when I consulted with a professor at my university, he reviewed the conference and noted that it wasn’t listed among the well-known conferences and journals he recommended. He suggested that it might be an unranked or less reputable venue and advised considering withdrawing my paper and submitting it to a higher-tier Q1 journal instead.
As I am new to my PhD program, I'm seeking advice on how to identify reputable journals and conferences. Should I consider withdrawing my paper and preparing it for a Q1 journal?

Can you be a bit more specific, regarding your field for isntance, the conference you are applying in and so on?

Yes, it is a conference on the internet and the web, and the journal appears in https://oaji.net/journals-list.html?letter=I. But apparently the list does not really provide ranking of the journal. And the conference also not highly considered by few professors whose opinion I asked for. On the other hand, I am new in PhD and do not know yet what to make of this or that conference etc.

You still did not write exact name of the conference and the name of the journal where the top paper from the proceedings would go.

The second on the list. If you can share about its academic ranking/merits - please do.

Well apparently most the journals listed in the link are new to me and tried to check the credibility of different forums, and it turned out they either sham or mediocre ones.

This link (https://journalseeker.researchbib.com/view/issn/1645-7641) suggests that it does not even have an impact factor(IF), which is a strong indicator that it is not a good one.

If you were you, I would search good conferences from IEEE conferences database (https://conferences.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/search?q=web&virtualflag=B&virtualConfReadOnly=N)

Okay, thanks a lot. How do I withdraw accepted paper? I simply write them I want to withdraw it?

Yes, or if you submitted through any online submission portal (that is normally the case), there should be an option to withdraw your submission.

@NaveedAhmed, forgot before to link the conference: here it is, http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/servlet/event.showcfp?eventid=180226&copyownerid=118738 Can you please share if the conference too is unknown? Also, do you have any recommendation for conferences dealing with multidisciplinary issues involving communication (from social perspective), internet, and information?

Yes, even the conference is not publishing the proceedings on some decent platforms. I read this statement "The conference proceedings will be submitted (pending approval) to the following indexing services (among others):". But again this is a big question mark as you never know when would they get approval. Don't lose hope, there are so many other conferences (I shared the link above) where you can send your paper. Good Luck!

Thank you so very much! You have been very helpful.

"when I consulted with a professor at my university, he reviewed the conference and noted that it wasn’t listed among the well-known conferences and journals he recommended" - You should always consult with your advisor before submitting something. If they've provided you a list of conferences and journals to submit to, I would never assume that you should set that list aside and submit someplace else.
